# Ignoring a folder using tsc

Tags: typescript, types, tsconfig, tsc

I have written a project in which there are no problems with typing, but during development I had to use old components. They do not have good typing and therefore there are a lot of errors and because of this I put them in a certain folder (which I want to ignore). Unfortunately there is no way to rewrite it. And when using tsc I have a lot of problems with them due to poorly typed components. I really don’t want to disable pre-commit checks with the tsc command

I tried to imitate: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/practical-boyd-469gqd?file=%2Fsrc%2Ftest%2Ftest.tsx

```
ts.config
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/custom-components/*"
  ]
}
```

Use exclude and other comman widt tsc

Comment: Exclude will remove the file from build. If you need the file content, you can just at `@ts-nocheck` at the start of file

Comment: I have a huge folder and there are a lot of files with errors.

Comment: You can move these files to same folder then, you can create another `tsconfig.json` in there by inheriting from root then overriding some like, `strict: false`. It would be much easier in my opinion

Comment: did not help ((

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, there are 2 solutions

1. rename the files to js
2. add to ts-nochesk
   But I have more than 100 files and that’s why I wrote a function on node js which goes through all files with the extension ts, tsx and adds this line to the beginning

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function processFilesWithExtensions(rootDir, extensions) {
  // Читаем содержимое директории
  const files = fs.readdirSync(rootDir);

  // Перебираем файлы в директории
  for (const file of files) {
    const filePath = path.join(rootDir, file);
    const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      // Если это директория, рекурсивно вызываем функцию для этой директории
      processFilesWithExtensions(filePath, extensions);
    } else if (stat.isFile()) {
      // Если это файл, проверяем его расширение
      const fileExtension = path.extname(file).toLowerCase();
      if (extensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
        // Если расширение файла соответствует заданным, добавляем комментарий в начало файла
        const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
        const newContent = `/* stylelint-disable */\n${content}`;
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, newContent);
      }
    }
  }
}

const rootDirectory = 'custom-components'; // Укажите путь к вашей корневой директории
const allowedExtensions = ['.scss']; // Расширения, для которых нужно добавить комментарий

processFilesWithExtensions(rootDirectory, allowedExtensions);
```

don't forget to install the file fs